# woocommerce-bookings modify date output to include custom text per product or category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need this filter to only be added/triggered on a specific post id.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', 10, 3 );

function woocommerce_cart_item_product( $item_data, $cart_item){

if ( ! empty( $cart_item['booking'] ) ) {
    $date_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_date_format', wc_date_format() );
    $time_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_time_format', ', ' . wc_time_format() );
    $end_date = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_get_end_date_with_time', date_i18n( $date_format, $cart_item['booking']['_end_date'] ) );
    $item_data[] = array(
        'key'    => __( 'for the week of', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'value'   => $cart_item['booking']['_end_date'],
        'display' => $end_date,
    );
}

return $item_data;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`$cart_item` argument have all the details you want about the product that is being added to cart.

```
$cart_item[ 'product_id' ] // Product Id ( the product that is being added to cart )
$cart_item[ 'variation_id' ] // Variable product's id  ( if that product is a variable )
$cart_item[ 'variation' ] // Variation array ( if that product is a variable )
$cart_item[ 'quantity' ] // Line Item quantity
$cart_item[ 'data' ] // Post object of the product that is being added
```

So your code should look like this.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_cart_item_product( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( !empty( $cart_item['booking'] ) && $cart_item["product_id"] == "Your Product Id" ) {
        $date_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_date_format', wc_date_format() );
        $time_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_time_format', ', ' . wc_time_format() );
        $end_date = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_get_end_date_with_time', date_i18n( $date_format, $cart_item['booking']['_end_date'] ) );
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'    => __( 'for the week of', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'value'   => $cart_item['booking']['_end_date'],
            'display' => $end_date,
        );
    }
    return $item_data;
}
```

Replace that `"Your Product Id"` with your specific post id.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where this code is executed this should work:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', 10, 3 );

function woocommerce_cart_item_product( $item_data, $cart_item) {

    global $post;

    if ( ! empty( $cart_item['booking'] ) && $post->ID == YOURUNIQUEIDHERE ) {
        $date_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_date_format', wc_date_format() );
        $time_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_time_format', ', ' . wc_time_format() );
        $end_date = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_get_end_date_with_time', date_i18n( $date_format, $cart_item['booking']['_end_date'] ) );
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'    => __( 'for the week of', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'value'   => $cart_item['booking']['_end_date'],
            'display' => $end_date,
        );
    }

    return $item_data;

}
```

I've added an extra check for the Post ID in your if-statement. Here you can replace YOURUNIQUEIDHERE with the ID of any post you want. Hope this helps you out!

Comment: `global $post;` object won't be available at the time of `add to cart` event, because there is no WP loop involved that time.